How to Move /var on an Ubuntu VM Hosted in Azure
I have a need to move the /var directory of all of my Ubuntu VMs (22.04) hosted in Azure to a separate partition from the OS. Is the only safe way to do this via the serial console in the Azure portal using single-user mode? I would like to be able to script this, because we use scripts to create our VMs in some instances. However, using the serial console would mean I cannot script it (I think).
I do wonder if it would be possible via the Azure CLI script to:

Create a small data disk for the /var directory.
Attach the disk to the VM and format/partition it.
Edit /etc/fstab to tell the OS to mount /var to the new disk on boot, but do not mount the new disk yet.
Stop and deallocate the VM and detach both the OS and data disks.
Spin up a temp VM and mount both the OS and data disks to it.
Copy the /var directory from the OS disk over to the data disk.
Reattach and start the VM.

I pretty much know how to write all the scripts to do that, but I am wondering if it would work safely/reliably all the time.
I am guessing that if I wanted to make this a part of my scripts for creating VMs, the easiest thing would be to create my own baseline OS image, as the ones Canonical provides all start with /var on the main OS partition.
